# Persist values between two action results in one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, controller

I am generating values in one action method of a controller. How can I use the same variables values in another action result from the same controller?

For example:

Controller A - Action result 1 :

```
 public ActionResult CalculationsONE()
{       
        dynamic CalcModel = new ExpandoObject();
        int var1 = //Value calculated here
        int var2 = //Calculation

        CalcModel.Var1= var1;
        CalcModel.Var2= var2;

        return View(CalcModel);

}
```

Controller A - Action result 2:

```
  public ActionResult CalculationsTWO()
{       
   // I want to use var1 and var2 from the CalculationsONE in 
     this action result

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply pass them as query string parameters:

```
public ActionResult CalculationsTWO(int var1, int var2)
{       
    ...
}
```

and in order to invoke the `CalculationsTWO` action from within the view rendered in `CalculationsONE` action you could generate a link like this:

```
@model CalcModel
@Html.ActionLink(
    "call calculations2", 
    "calculationstwo", 
    "somecontroller" 
    new { 
        var1 = Model.Var1, 
        var2 = Model.Var2 
    }
)
```

Oh, and I would recommend you using strongly typed view models instead of dynamic objects passed to the view. `ViewBag` is dynamic but honestly, use view models. You will be happier :-)

Comment: In real scenarios changing the action contract for these kind of reasons would not be a good idea.

Comment: @Jani, why? Adapting the controller action signature to meet the values passed from the view seems like a good idea to me. Even in real world scenarios. I do it all the time. It's called refactoring. In this case the action needs 2 values, so it seems reasonable to me to adapt the action signature to take those 2 values as arguments.

Comment: But when 2nd method was defined without any parameter it means somewhere it was called without any parameter and it was meaningful and changing the signature of that action for sake of aonther action seem irrational IMHO

Comment: @Jani, I doubt it because right now the OP is not able to get the two variables inside the second action. So this second action doesn't even exist as he is not capable of implementing it. But I agree that if the action existed somehow, he changes its implementation anyway, so it seems reasonable to me to change the way it is called as well.

Comment: @darin    How do I write "@model CalcModel" in aspx syntax.

Comment: @ZVenue, like this: `<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CalcModel>" %>`.

Comment: I am passing only nulls when I do this? Is it because I am using a dynamic model.. How can I create a quick view model ? I did the dynamic because earlier my requirement was just to display the values on the view page.. but now I am trying to export values on press of a button.

Comment: @ZVenue, simply define a view model: `public class MyViewModel { public int Var1 { get; set; } public int Var2 { get; set; } }`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Okay now I have a new view model. How can I assign the calculated values in my controller to the newly created properties in the view model. I mean how do I assign calculated value var1 to Var1 property of the view model

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6167/discussion-between-zvenue-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 0):

If they are two separate actions the above answer from Darin Dimitrov should do it otherwise if you want both results in one resource call create two private methods in your controller that do calc1 and calc2 and return the results to the view...

```
results: {
   calc1: ....
   calc2: ....
}
```

you can use class vars like you currently are to keep track of the values.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative I would go about it in way of saving your variables into session.

EG:

```
this.Session["variable"]


this.HttpContext.Session["variable"]
```

or pass them via ViewData["string"] into view and in Controller on Request.FormData["VariableName"] to bind it back

another way is 
add the data to model for the view
and on postback in your controller bind the model back into variable

eg:

```
// postback action
public ActionResult RebindMethod(ModelToUse rebindToMyModel){

}
```

Where Model definition is:

```
public class ModelToUse{
    public string MyVariableToPersist{get;set;}
}
```